# Was "Adam" referred to somewhere, beside GOTG 2?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2

The post-credit scene in *Guardians of the Galaxy 2* introduces *Adam* ([Warlock](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Warlock)?)

Is he mentioned anywhere else in the MCU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is infact an easter egg in GotG 1 and in Thor: Dark World at the Collectors collection.

However there are **no mentions** of him in any way, in the MCU, besides GotG2, past the easter eggs.

[image: picture]

[In this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGWbGXXJT1s) in Dark World.

Here's another [clip on youtube](https://youtu.be/tTFW7rz40fo?t=20) from GotG1
[image]

Comment: Official  wording for first cacoon from GotG https://www.cinemablend.com/news/1675739/how-the-first-guardians-of-the-galaxy-movies-cocoon-ties-into-vol-2